# Installing Realm Database, Build Fails? Have I done it right, and do I need to update CocoaPods or Carthage?

Tags: swift, database, xcode, realm, cocoapods

[image]

Following the instructions for downloading the Realm Database and I need your help to solve the error I receive when the build failed. Build was successful before I attempted to instal the Realm Database.

Error : - "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

I've downloaded the file for Realm Database, and added the `RealmSwift.framework` and `Realm.framework` from the Xcode 11.5 file into the Navigator panel in my project. I've selected 'copy items if needed' checkbox and hit Finish.

In the Targets Settings page in the 'General' tab, I have the `Realm.framework` and `RealmSwift.Framework` under the 'Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content' section, with 'Do not embed' showing under the 'Embed' column. I have seen some other installation videos showing that this needs to be Embedded, but do I 'Embed & Sign' or 'Embed Without Signing'?

In the Targets Settings 'Build Settings' tab, under the 'Search Paths' > 'Framework Search Paths' section, I have added 'RealmSwift.framework' with the left column showing 'Any Architecture | Any SDK'.

In the Targets Settings 'Build Phases' tab, I've hit the + then 'New Run Script Phase'. In the new 'Run Script' section I have removed the `'#...'` holding text, and replaced with `bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"`

Do I need to also check my current version of CocoaPods, and or download Carthage, as the 'Installation' section of the download page isn't crystal clear to me?

I have Xcode 11.5 installed on my iMac.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: You are going through a lot of extra steps that are not needed to add Realm to a project. Ensure cocoapods is updated, create a pod file and install it. I recommend cocoapods.app as it's very simple. If you're having issues with the podfile, include it in your question.

Comment: Thanks for feedback Jay. I downloaded Realm the 'Dynamic Framework' method. I've now uninstalled the above, removed all references from Xcode project and installed Cocoapods through Ruby (all new to me!). Not seen Cocoapods.app before, but I've just installed it. 

I appreciate there is a guide to installing with through Cocoapods on Realm, but how do I run `pod repo update` to make CocoaPods aware of the latest available Realm versions. Would this be through Terminal, or somehow in Cocoapods.app?

I've attempted the above in Terminal, and am not sure what action to take next. Any advice?

Comment: You don't need Ruby at all, you can just get cocoapods.app from the [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org) website. Updating is just a single command `sudo gem install cocoapods` and is covered in the [Cocoapods Getting Started Guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html). When you need to update your Realm file for example, I suggest pushing the easy button; open the podfile with cocoapods.app and select 'Update' from the Install button in the upper right corner of the window. You can also use terminal by navigating to the project directory and issue 'pod update'

Comment: Oh... see [pod install vs pod update](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html) and always ensure your project is completely *closed* before doing any updates.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the Cocoapods to v 1.9.3. Following the instructions on Realm, I've made Cocoapods aware of the latest versions. Step 3 asks to add `use_frameworks` and `pod_RealmSwift` to my main and test targets in my pod file. How would I make a Podfile?! I've tried adding a Podfile manually through Cocoapods App, and no files appear? I've selected a test Xcode project, it gives me the option to 'Open" and nothing happens on click?

Comment: Mac User NewTestProject.xcodeproj % /Users/UserName/Documents/Realm\ Install/Realm\ Install pod install
zsh: permission denied: /Users/UserName/Documents/NewTestProject/NewTestProject
Mac User NewTestProject.xcodeproj % pod update
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
Mac User NewTestProject.xcodeproj % pod init
[!] No Xcode project found, please specify one
Mac User NewTestProject.xcodeproj %

Tried adding a podfile manually, and I'm getting no joy? I've tried adding to the Path File itself and the Path File Location Folder, with the same results

Comment: For anyone that is on this page; 
after many, many hours I have finally installed Realm and attached to my Project as a Workspace! 

In terminal, ensure you type CG and drag "Your project location" direct from Finder then hit return before you do anything else fro the guides!

The two pages below and Jay really helped! Although, I didn't use Cocoapods.apps, I don't think?! 

https://docs.realm.io/sync/v/3.x/getting-started-1/ios-quick-start/step-1-my-first-realm-app

https://medium.com/@soufianerafik/how-to-add-pods-to-an-xcode-project-2994aa2abbf1

Comment: Glad you got it working! Again though - it's a 2 minute process if you use cocoapods.app

Comment: Believe me when I say I was on the Mac from 1-5:30pm trying to install it!! Such a relief. Now to learn how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to specific question for the page: Don't download through Dynamic Framework, download through CocoaPods instead. So much simpler.